# Changing left margin in itemize environment of beamer class

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, lists, indentation, itemize

I can't figure out how to line up the symbols of an itemize environment in beamer with the left part of the main text. In other words, I would like to supress the left margin in beamer itemize lists.

It would be nice if the solution worked with any itemize label defined with

```
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[]
```

In order to make myself clearer, what beamer produces by default is something like:

```
Main text. Main text. Main text...
   * Item 1
   * Item 2
   * Item 3
   ....
```

and the desired result is

```
Main text. Main text. Main text...
* Item 1
* Item 2
* Item 3
....
```

Answer (score 59):

The beamer class uses the same default lengths for the left margin like the base classes: `\leftmargini`, `\leftmarginii` etc. So you could adjust those lenghts. For instance:

```
\setlength{\leftmargini}{0pt}
```

You may insert any value instead of `0pt` that fits for you.

Further requirements might require a redefiniton or patch of beamer's itemize environment. If you would like to have such complete control over the itemize environment, you could redefine it this way within your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\itemize}[1][]{%
  \beamer@ifempty{#1}{}{\def\beamer@defaultospec{#1}}%
  \ifnum \@itemdepth >2\relax\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@itemdepth\@ne
    \beamer@computepref\@itemdepth% sets \beameritemnestingprefix
    \usebeamerfont{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body begin}%
    \list
      {\usebeamertemplate{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}}
      {\def\makelabel##1{%
          {%
            \hss\llap{{%
                \usebeamerfont*{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}%
                \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}##1}}%
          }%
        }%
      }
  \fi%
  \beamer@cramped%
  \raggedright%
  \beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip%
}
\makeatother
```

Until now it's just a copy of the original! But since it's in your preamble, you can modify it.

For example, replace `\hss\llap` by `\rlap` and the bullets will align with the text around:

```
...
      {\def\makelabel##1{%
          {%
            \rlap{{%
                \usebeamerfont*{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}%
...
```

Within this redefinition you could adjust the LaTeX list length macros. This requires to know how to work with the LaTeX list environment.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, but your code hangs the item labels out into the margin and this is not what I want. Of course, I could change the left margin to a nonzero value, but how could I do it sistematically for itemize lists with any label?

Comment: @rgallego: I added a redefinition which could give you a start. If you should have a question regarding LaTeX's `list` environment, you may post it on the site as well.

Comment: This does only seem to align the bullet-points, but the text of the items is still placed on the same position, which leaves an ugly gap between the bullet-points and the text. Is there a way to change that too?

Comment: Where do I put the code `\setlength{\leftmargini}{0pt}`?

Comment: @LWZ Into the preamble, as usual.

Comment: What are the default values for `\leftmargini`, `\leftmarginii` and `\leftmarginiii` in beamer?

Answer (score 30):

This seemed to work for me:

```
\settowidth{\leftmargini}{\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}
\addtolength{\leftmargini}{\labelsep}
```

Comment: What's nice about this solution is that exactly answers the OP's question, i.e., the left edge of the bullets is aligned with the left margin of normal text.

Comment: +1 ``\addtolength{\leftmargini}{-2\labelsep}`` for radical tightness.

Comment: This works for the `Madrid` theme :)

Comment: Where should be put this code piece?