# Reducing left margin inside a TikZ node

Tags: tikz-pgf, indentation, nodes

I would like to reduce the left margin inside this node:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, text width=11em, text centered, minimum height=4em]
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=6cm, auto, >=stealth]
\node[block] (Example) 
{\textbf{Example}
\begin{itemize}
\item First item: string
\item Second item: float
\item Third item: float
\end{itemize}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'll appreciate a lot any help or advice!

Answer (score 6):

The margin isn't introduced by the TikZ node, but by the enumerate environment. You can move your list to the left by adjusting the `\leftmargini` length, as explained in the answer to [Changing left margin in itemize environment of beamer class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5941/changing-left-margin-in-itemize-environment-of-beamer-class/5954#5954).

`\setlength{\leftmargini}{1.3em}` works quite well in this case:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{block/.style={rectangle,
  draw,
  text width=11em,
  text centered,
  minimum height=4em,
  execute at begin node={\setlength{\leftmargini}{1.3em}}
}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=6cm, auto, >=stealth]
\node[block] (Example) 
{\textbf{Example}
\begin{itemize}
\item First item: string
\item Second item: float
\item Third item: float
\end{itemize}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: TikZ node with itemize environment and reduced left margin]

You can automatically execute this command in all of your `block` nodes by adding the key `execute at begin node={\setlength{\leftmargini}{1.3em}}` to the style definition.

On a side note, the PGF v 2.1 syntax for defining styles is `\tikzset{<style name>/.style={<options>}}` (instead of `\tikzset{<style name>}=[<options>]`).