# Indentation in itemize list in Beamer class

Tags: beamer, indentation

Hi I usually write whole beamer presentations in bulleted list which creates automatic indentation which produce odd looking lot of left margin space. I want to start bulleted list like normal text without indentation. I tried packages like `\usepackage{enumitem}` which is not working in beamer. Kindly suggest some solution

Comment: Do the answers to this question help you? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5941/134144

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?