# Increasing left margin in itemize environment of beamer class

Tags: beamer, margins

My question is like 
[Changing left margin in itemize environment of beamer class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5941/changing-left-margin-in-itemize-environment-of-beamer-class)
except that I want to increase the left margin by maybe 15ex, while that question sought to suppress the left margin.  I will add that one answer to that question noted that it requires to know how to work with the LaTeX list environment.  I do not know how.

Answer (score 3):

The left margin of itemizations is controlled by `\leftmargini`. To only modify it for a single itemization, you can place both inside a a group.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

    \begin{itemize}
    \item abc
    \end{itemize}

\begingroup
    \addtolength{\leftmargini}{15ex}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item abc
    \end{itemize}
\endgroup

    \begin{itemize}
    \item abc
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess I could always when a new beamer question appears hold my breath until your answer pops up and would survive it. ;-) (+1)

Comment: Ah.  I would like to do this for just one enumeration, although the document has many others in it.

Comment: @marmot That's exactly what I do for new tikz questions until your answer appears :)

Comment: @ColinMcLarty If you only want it for a single enumeration, use it inside a group with this enumeration, see my edited answer