how adjust the itemize and enumerate environments to have a smaller left margin?
i use this template , but the left margin of item and itemize is so big and if i insert figure in slide look like this

    \documentclass[dvipsnames,mathserif]{beamer}
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
    \setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=black}
    \setbeamerfont{footline}{series=\bfseries}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    %\usetheme{Frankfurt}%1
    \usetheme{Darmstadt}%1
    \usepackage{multicol}
    % for RTL liste
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand{\RTListe}{\raggedleft\rightskip\leftm}
    \newcommand{\leftm}{\@totalleftmargin}
    \makeatother
    
    % RTL frame title
    \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
    {\vspace*{-1mm}
      \nointerlineskip
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,ht=2.2em,wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
            \vbox{}\vskip-2ex%
            \strut\hskip1ex\insertframetitle\strut
            \vskip-0.8ex%
        \end{beamercolorbox}
    }
    % align subsection in toc
    \makeatletter
    \setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}
    {\leavevmode\rightskip=5ex%
      \llap{\raise0.1ex\beamer@usesphere{subsection number projected}{bigsphere}\kern1ex}%
      \inserttocsubsection\par%
    }
    \makeatother
    
    % RTL triangle for itemize
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\scriptsize\raise1.25pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleleft$}} 
    
    %\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\rule{4pt}{4pt}}
    
    \defbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{square2}
    {\LR{
        %
        \hbox{%
        \usebeamerfont*{item projected}%
        \usebeamercolor[bg]{item projected}%
        \vrule width2.25ex height1.85ex depth.4ex%
        \hskip-2.25ex%
        \hbox to2.25ex{%
          \hfil%
          {\color{fg}\insertenumlabel}%
          \hfil}%
      }%
    }}
    
    \setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[square2]
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    
    
    \titlegraphic { 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture, opacity=0.1,]
    \node[] at (0, 5){
        \includegraphics[width=0.63\textwidth]{Conference Logo.png}
    };\end{tikzpicture}}
    \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body begin}{\vspace{-0.5ex}\leftskip=1ex}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Summary} 
\footnotesize \tableofcontents 
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}{Motivation}
\scriptsize
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize} [<+-| alert@+>]

\scriptsize
\item Curved beams are popular structural elements in various engineering fields
\begin{itemize}
\item They offer high stiffness-to-weight ratio, making them an efficient choice for load-bearing structures
\item they provide esthetic appeal and enable the creation of complex, free-form shapes in architectural designs
\item Their ability to distribute loads efficiently and resist bending moments makes them suitable for applications such as bridges, roofs, and aircraft structures
\end{itemize}

\item Curved beams often experience large deformations under various loading conditions, necessitating the use of nonlinear analysis calculation.
\item Developing accurate and efficient nonlinear beam elements for large deformation is challenging
\begin{itemize}
\item Capturing the accurate response of curved beams under large deformations is crucial for ensuring the safety and reliability of structures
\item Developing efficient and accurate nonlinear beam elements poses significant challenges due to the complex nature of the problem
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]
{curved2.jpg}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}


Please add a compilable test file and only ask about one problem per question. You probably want to change the \leftmargini to change the left margin of items

yes , that's what I want

Then please edit your question so that we  can reproduce your problem.

Probably a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5941/changing-left-margin-in-itemize-environment-of-beamer-class

I try it , not work

Then please update your question and add a compilable test document

Did you test your code? It should throw an error because there is no document environment.


the document environment is missing

the mathserif option is obsolete, use \usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif} instead. A warning in the log file will tell you this. Please don't ignore warnings.

you don't need to load graphicx, beamer does this automatically

it doesn't make a lot of sense to load the multicol package. Beamer has its own column mechanism

if you change the font size of the first level items, you should change the font size of the second (and third) level items as well

you waste a lot of space by setting the whole frame in two columns

please reconsider if you want to inflict a slide with so much text on your audience.


... and then for what you actually asked about: you can change the left margin of items with \setlength{\leftmargini}{0cm} etc.

\documentclass[dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}%1
%\usepackage{multicol}

% RTL triangle for itemize
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\scriptsize\raise1.25pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleleft$}} 
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setlength{\leftmargini}{0cm}
\setlength{\leftmarginii}{0.5cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Motivation}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate body}{size=\scriptsize}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subbody}{size=\scriptsize}
\begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]
\item Curved beams are popular structural elements in various engineering fields
\begin{itemize}
\item They offer high stiffness-to-weight ratio, making them an efficient choice for load-bearing structures
\item they provide esthetic appeal and enable the creation of complex, free-form shapes in architectural designs
\item Their ability to distribute loads efficiently and resist bending moments makes them suitable for applications such as bridges, roofs, and aircraft structures
\end{itemize}

\item Curved beams often experience large deformations under various loading conditions, necessitating the use of nonlinear analysis calculation.
\item Developing accurate and efficient nonlinear beam elements for large deformation is challenging
\end{itemize}
\vskip-.5\baselineskip
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item[] 
\begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]
\item Capturing the accurate response of curved beams under large deformations is crucial for ensuring the safety and reliability of structures
\item Developing efficient and accurate nonlinear beam elements poses significant challenges due to the complex nature of the problem
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]
{example-image-duck}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}



It didn't work for me unfortunately, I don't know where the problem is

Unless you provide code that allows me to replicate your problems, it is hard to guess what might go wrong in your code.

I tried your code just as it is, but the left margin did not change and the column style appeared for all the text, not for the 02 last text like you

Can you show the exact same code you tried? It does not sound as if it is really the same as in my answer.

Now it work (your code ) the problem was in the figure
but when i add  the modification that you suggest in my code not work
your code that you provide work perfect
